# Member variable has different addresses in each method

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

I have this code (minimal example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;

    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        foo();  // foo() gets called
    }

    void test() override {
        std::cout << "Derived test" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo() {
        static_cast<T&>(*this).bar(); // call method from child
    }
};

class Final : public Derived<Final> {
public:
    void test() override {
        std::cout << "Final::test(): " << &var << std::endl;
    }

    void bar() {
        std::cout << "Final::bar(): " <<  &var << std::endl;
    }

    int var;

};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> a = std::make_unique<Final>(Final());
    a->test();

    return 0;
}
```

Now here is the problem. The variable `var` is actually different in method `Final::test()` and `Final::bar()`. This is apparent from the output of the code abode:

```
Final::bar(): 0x7ffee5ad3988
Final::test(): 0x7fb8dbc017b8
```

I believe this is due to something with inheritance and virtual dispatch, but I can't figure out why this happens. Could you help me please?
I would be also thankful if you could help me figure out a way to get rid if CRTP and only stick to inheritance - now I can't since I need to call virtual method from constructor of `Derived`.

Comment: `std::make_unique<Final>(Final());` -> `std::make_unique<Final>();`?

Comment: I need to be able to call `test()` on pointer to the `Base` class. However even with your proposed change the addresses are still different.

Comment: "_I need to be call test() from pointer to the Base class._" How does my change not allow that? I meant: `std::unique_ptr<Base> a = std::make_unique<Final>(Final());` -> `std::unique_ptr<Base> a = std::make_unique<Final>();` As seen running [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vqmgJIhHrREJLoLE). `Final ()` creates a temporary object (that prints said output), and the object gets copied into `std::unique_ptr`. You don't overload copy-constructor, hence don't see output from it. Hence, from my initial point of view - the issue was borderline typo.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm just trying to follow here, I would have guess it used the move-constructor, am I missing something ?

Comment: When you call `foo`, the `Final` part of the object has not been constructed yet (its initialisation hasn't even begun), and `static_cast<T&>(*this).bar();` has undefined behaviour. Also, don't make virtual calls in constructors.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sorry I misread your question, I thought you wanted to use `std::unique_ptr<Final>` as type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't figure out why this happens. Could you help me please?

It's just another *undefined behavior*.

When you construct the `Final` object with the statement `std::make_unique<Final>(...)`, the hierarchy of constructors are called (in the proper order).

```
Final::Final() calls Derived::Derived()
```

However, the constructor of `Derived` calls `foo()`, which performs a cast and calls `bar()`.
When `bar()` is invoked, `Final` constructor is not completed yet. That leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you, looks like this was the case. I replaced constructor with virtual `init()` method and it works now.